# Web-Service orchestration for a CRUD webservices

Tags: database, web-services, crud, esb, orchestration

I have 4 web services providing CRUD methods to 4 different simple databases(1 table by databse).
What I want to do is to create another web service which call the aforementioned services to gather some specific data, the data requested might be in one database or in the four databases.
I've tried to work with orchestration (ow2 Orchestra) but I've found that is for business processes, and in my case  I only have services representing a CRUD application for a database.
I've also thinked of using an ESB, but it seems a labourious task for simple case study as mine.
Do I have to create manually this web service or there is another approach ?

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done a lot of work with Mule ESB - development, design, running in production, etc. I would say an ESB would be overkill for you. If all you need to do is have one wrapper web service that calls 1-4 other web services, I would keep it simple and just implement it manually.

An ESB requires a server to run your projects on and there is a fairly large learning curve.

It would be easier to learn how to make the web service yourself compared to learning the ESB. It would also be easier to maintain a web service as opposed to an ESB.

However if you are going to have web services multiplying all over the place, then an ESB might make sense.